# How to assign attributes to an instance during creation?

Tags: python

I am still learning Python and I am a little confused about creating new instances.  At the bottom of this example I am creating an instance of BgImages.  I wanted to assign it a string, so I added collidetext="this is a test" and then I went into the BgImages constructor and simply put self.collidetext="random string".  The problem is when I print slum.collisiontext, it still prints "random string" rather than "this is a test".

I have asked for help on this from other people and I am now understanding that it has something to do with **kwargs won't allow what I am trying to do.  I was hoping someone could tell me how I can achieve what I am trying to accomplish and why what I'm doing does not work (in layman's terms).

```
class BgImages(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.collidetext="random string"

    def collisiontext(self,**kwargs):
        return self.collidetext()

class MainCharacter(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainCharacter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)



class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        slum=BgImages(source='slum.png', collidetext="this is a test1")
        police=BgImages(source='police.png', collidetext="this is a test2")
        listofwidgets=[]
        listofwidgets.append(slum)
        listofwidgets.append(police)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the issue somewhat with your use of `kwargs`. But anyway, to do what you want in your current code you can do something like this:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.collidetext=kwargs["collidetext"]
```

However, normally you would use actual named parameters, maybe like this:

```
def __init__(self, source=None, collidetext=None):
    super(Npcs, self).__init__(source=source)
    self.collidetext=collidetext
```

Also your use of `def collisiontext(self,**kwargs):` indicates that you aren't really sure what `kwargs` is for and you're just repeating the pattern. I suggest spending some time with a good Python tutorial before you get too much further.

Comment: I used your bottom example and it worked, although source=None made all my images disappear, so I removed that part.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't understand why it doesn't work without source=None.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested spending some time with a Python tutorial. For example, [sections 4.6 and 4.7 of the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) explain function parameters in depth.

Comment: The language they are using is too dense and I have read through this tutorial before.  Believe it or not this is my second year trying to learn Python and I'm still at this low of a level.  Is there any other tutorial or documentation you can recommend so that I can understand function parameters?

Comment: Other popular Python tutorials include http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ and http://www.learnpython.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the desired keyword arguments correctly, but you are not using them in your target class.

```
class BgImages(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Npcs, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # do a dictionary lookup to get a random string if the argument is not passed
        self.collidetext= kwargs.get("collidetext","random string")
```